# Typeahead.js - Is it possible to turn off autocomplete by clicking a link in the footer?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I have an autocomplete textbox using typeahead.js in the bootstrap framework. Now I need an option called "turn off autocomplete" after the suggestion list. I have a footer in js using below code.

I need an option for adding a link like "Turn off autocomplete". I am able to add it by footer like below.

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'search',
        local: ['USA', 'UK', 'INDIA', 'Australia', 'Austria',],
        limit: 2,
    minLength: 3,
        footer :
         '< div class="footer">'+
                '< span >< a >Turn off auto-complete< /a >< /span >' +
            '< /div > ' 
    });
```

But I am not able to get any event like click or hover. Can anyone suggest how can we get the event?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jsfiddle with one way of doing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/p7hfS/

The key features are to define your footer e.g.

```
footer:'<b><span class="fakeLink" id="fakeLink">Turn off autocomplete</span></b>'
```

And then set-up an event handler for this link, which will destroy the typeahead autocomplete functionality, making it behave thenceforth as an ordinary input control e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '#fakeLink', function () {
    $('#movies').typeahead('destroy');
});
```

The only task you'll have left is to ensure that the style of the ordinary input control looks the same as a typeahead initialised one.